# Cannot log in to google game services

Tags: android, google-play-games

I'm writing a simple app in android O and would like to connect to google game services to use the realtime game service.

I've gone through the documentation, but cannot find any error.

I have a button on the xml to activate the loggin:

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/goButton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

On onCreate I have this:

```
    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN);
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
```

then on the listener for clicks:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.sign_in_button:
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Sign-in button clicked");
                clickedSignIn(v);
                break;
        ...
        ...
    }

    public void clickedSignIn(View view) {
        Log.d("MainActivity","clickedSignIn");
        startActivityForResult(mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(), RC_SIGN_IN);
    }




    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {

            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task =
                   GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);

            try {
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                onConnected(account);
            } catch (ApiException apiException) {
                String message = apiException.getMessage();
                if (message == null || message.isEmpty()) {
                    message = "Unknown error on sign-in.";
                }

                onDisconnected();

                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setMessage(message)
                        .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                        .show();
            }
        }

    }
```

For some reason I don't understand, I don't get any kind of sign in view or message (I thought that is what it is supposed to happen), and get a null sign in result which translates into the message "sign in error".

I have added the app for testing in game services in play.google.publish, the user is added as a testing user.

I followed the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/signin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing adding the app id to the manifiest file as described here: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart#step_3_modify_your_code